# Does Google Cloud Vision save client`s input data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I use service on Google Cloud Platform, Google Cloud Vision.

I am worry about the Google service save on its server my input data.

Is anyone to say about my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the synchronous annotate methods, it doesn't save your data.

For the async annotate methods, it saves data during processing of the long-running operation and then deletes it.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage